# PHP GMail SMTP Failure

Tags: php, smtp

I have used this [swiftmailer](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer)
The PHP code seems to work but ultimately this does nothing.
I hope someone dealt with this repo could help me.

```
<?php
    require_once 'swiftmailer/vendor/autoload.php';

    // Create the Transport
    $transport = (new Swift_SmtpTransport('smtp.gmail.com', 465))
      ->setEncryption('ssl')    
      ->setUsername('alice@wonderland')
      ->setPassword("zxcfA!0987")
    ;

    // Create the Mailer using your created Transport
    $mailer = new Swift_Mailer($transport);

    // Create a message
    $message = (new Swift_Message('Wonderful Subject'))
      ->setFrom(['john@doe.com' => 'John Doe'])
      ->setTo(['bob@cling.com' => 'Bob'])
      ->setBody('Here is the message itself')
      ;

    // Send the message
    $result = $mailer->send($message);
```

Comment: what does "seems to work but ultimately this does nothing" actully mean?

Comment: no email sent and no error log but php script ends execution without any error.

Comment: my first port of call when debugging email is the mail server log - can you view that?

Comment: no I am not seeing.

Comment: if you don't have access to the server mail log look into the debugging options that come with swift mailer

Comment: This  is an opensource system and you can reproduce anything you need. This seems like chatting in the comment section.

Comment: no idea what you said, best of luck

Comment: https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials